# How Can I Retrieve a Word From JTextArea From a Right Click?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I would like the user to be able to store text depending on the which word is clicked in the text area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JTextComponent.getCaretPosition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getCaretPosition%28%29) is what you are looking for; and work from there on to find the word.
Or maybe getSelectedText, if you require the word to be selected by double click.

Answer (score 1):

A right click doesn't change the caret position so the getCaretPosition() method will only work if the caret is positioned on the word your want to select.

For a more general approach you might use the following in your MouseListener:

```
int offset = textArea.viewToModel( event.getPoint() );
int start = Utilities.getWordStart(textArea, offset);
int end = Utilities.getWordEnd(textArea, offset);
String text = textArea.getText(start, end - start);
```